# jQuery: check/uncheck checkboxes in two different tables simultaneously

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use dynamically generated rows for the form and I'm trying to check/uncheck checkboxes in two different tables simultaneously.
We say if user clicks on the first row at #Table1 should checkbox checked on the first row at #Table1 and #Table2. And this works fine. 
But nothing happens when the user tries to uncheck the same checkbox.
Can anyone help me to solve this ?

Here is my code:

```
$('#table1').on('click', 'tr', function (event) {
    var rowIdx = $(this).closest("tr").index();
    RowSelect($("#table1"), rowIdx);
    RowSelect($("#table2"), rowIdx);
    if (event.target.type !== 'checkbox') {
        $('.checkbox', this).trigger('click');
    }
    $("input[name='RemoveRowCheckbox']").change(function (event) {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $(this).closest('tr').addClass("CheckedRowColor");
        } else {
            $(this).closest('tr').removeClass("CheckedRowColor");
        }
    });
});
```

And here's [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/valder/a6qoxc7s/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `RowSelect` function twice (i.e for table 1 and 2) and setting checkbox always true. Actually for table 1 you need not to set checkbox again as you are clicking on it already. You just need to set checkbox from table2, so remove first call to Rowselect

```
//RowSelect($("#table1"), rowIdx);
```

now in RowSelect function, you need to set checkbox value in negation with previous value as shown below

```
function RowSelect(table, rowIdx) {
    var $chk = table.find("tr").eq(rowIdx).find("input[type=checkbox]");
    $chk.prop('checked', !$chk.is(':checked'));
};
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/a6qoxc7s/7/)**

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I wonder how can trigger this "on tr click" and not just "if checkbox checked"

Comment: did not understand what you are asking

Comment: Apologies, my question was a bit unclear. What I meant checkbox are checked at #Table2 only if the user clicks the checkbox at #Table1 and not when user clicks on the row at #Table1.

Comment: In `$('#table1').on('click', 'tr'` you are triggering click event for checkbox if target element is not checkbox which is causing rowSelect function calling twice and hence table2 checkbox getting check and then uncheck. I have made some change in `$('#table1').on('click', 'tr'`, please check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/a6qoxc7s/21/)